# Using array_diff() on arrays who holds several objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, array-difference

I have two arrays. The first array holds these values.

```
[a] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Chris
        [id] => AaKk4j0abEkJSSxYKKnss2LTZc9BmMDrYmm1TFxkIHR8PSU50OagCsl2pgJjVTm7MrkVBVcJgydJGViRU4HHClyWVm3arL4Y5cdWKyZQHtdltg
    )

[b] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => John
        [id] => AaL4_sWesWgGcHsd3eoBB3NDvpekzTQHE1J9zLUJs6zZPY7urzXzuhvA3uWuW0IOGiRJPznFsCIJFzZkm2_vIlSU93njnSwgiJbM1fmI9fUulw
    )

[c] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => James
        [id] => AaJ3g8G-nssIY7rhMq6pGMI5989ICREh7_MQ37Vre8oNuaBkO-HFgNUWcH2tZdyFwsWOv_kG4eVliss-FY_HmRFh4gmROJKkFCFKMjzatc_2iw
    )
```

The second array holds these values.

```
[d] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1003880559625244
        [name] => Aftab
    )

[e] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 448636891977424
        [name] => John
    )

[f] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 809530442478820
        [name] => James
    )

[g] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 809530442478820
        [name] => Chris
    )
```

I'm trying to compare both arrays and get only the values that do not match.
For Example in this case `Aftab` is the one who is not present in array 1 and is unique.
I have tried doing this with array_diff() function  in PHP but it is giving this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Are the name values unique in both arrays?

Comment: all the id are unique not the names.
i have to select all the names that does not match

Comment: The ID's in your example are not the same. If you have something that is unique and consistent within both record sets then just loop both arrays and replace the index with the consistent identifier and then use `array_diff_key()`

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_udiff` - Computes the difference of arrays by using a callback function for data comparison. http://us.php.net/array_udiff

```
function compare_names($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}
$newarr = array_udiff($b, $a, 'compare_names');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this for multidimensional array   

 $array1 = array(
        'a' => array('name' => 'Chris', 'id' => 'AaKk4j0abEkJSSxYKKnss2LTZc9BmMDrYmm1TFxkIHR8PSU50OagCsl2pgJjVTm7MrkVBVcJgydJGViRU4HHClyWVm3arL4Y5cdWKyZQHtdltg'),
        'b' => array('name' => 'John', 'id' => 'AaL4_sWesWgGcHsd3eoBB3NDvpekzTQHE1J9zLUJs6zZPY7urzXzuhvA3uWuW0IOGiRJPznFsCIJFzZkm2_vIlSU93njnSwgiJbM1fmI9fUulw'),
        'c' => array('name' => 'James', 'id' => 'AaJ3g8G-nssIY7rhMq6pGMI5989ICREh7_MQ37Vre8oNuaBkO-HFgNUWcH2tZdyFwsWOv_kG4eVliss-FY_HmRFh4gmROJKkFCFKMjzatc_2iw')
    );

    $array2 = array(
        'd' => array('name' => 'Aftab','id'=>'1003880559625244'),
        'e' => array('name' => 'John','id'=>'448636891977424'),
        'f' => array('name' => 'James','id'=>'809530442478820'),
        'g' => array('name' => 'Chris','id'=>'809530442478820'),
    );
    $result = check_diff_multi($array1, $array2);
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    print '</pre>';
    function check_diff_multi($array1, $array2){
        $result = array();
        foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
             if(isset($array2[$key])){
               if(is_array($val) && $array2[$key]){
                   $result[$key] = check_diff_multi($val, $array2[$key]);
               }
           } else {
               $result[$key] = $val;
           }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

To get your desired output

```
[d] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1003880559625244 [name] => Aftab ) 

$diff = array_udiff($array2,
$array1,
function($array2,$array1){
    return strcmp($array1["name"], $array2["name"]);
    }); 
    print_r($diff);
```

**Output :**

```
Array ( [d] => Array ( [name] => Aftab [id] => 1003880559625244 ) )
```

Comment: no brother its not working. its returning me the full second array.And these array are coming from an api

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: [d] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1003880559625244
        [name] => Aftab
    )

Comment: `$diff = array_udiff($array2,
$array1,
function($array2,$array1){
 return strcmp($array1["name"], $array2["name"]);
 }); 
 print_r($diff);`